# Cannot Play Video Output of Libavcodec (ffmpeg) Encoding Example

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, libavcodec

From FFMPEG's GitHub, I use the `encode_video.c` to generate a 1 second video. Here is the example in question: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_video.c

I compile with: `gcc -Wall -o ffencode encode_video.c -lavcodec -lavutil -lz -lm`

Clean compile, zero warnings.

I test the program by running: `./ffencode video.mp4 libx264`

Lots of stats printed out (expected based on source code) as well as ffmpeg logs, but ultimately no errors or warnings.

However, then the generated output `video.mp4`, can only be played by `ffplay`, and VLC Player (as well as Google Chrome) fail to play the video.

Playing it via `vlc` command line actually prints:

```
[00007ffd3550fec0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
TagLib: MP4: Invalid atom size
TagLib: MP4: Invalid atom size
TagLib: MP4: Invalid atom size
```

Looking at `ffprobe` output, the bitrate and duration fields are empty:

```
Input #0, h264, from 'video.mp4':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 352x288, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
```

I am using ffmpeg 4.1 with the following configuration:

```
ffprobe version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

Any ideas how to fix this? It is pretty surprising to see an API's official example to be lacking such basic information.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to perform muxing of your video stream into video container, such as `.mp4`. Muxing stuff is kept in libavformat. Algorithm should go like this:

- Initialize format library by invoking `av_register_all` or manually registering formats of interests.
- Create muxing context by invoking `avformat_alloc_context`
- Create one or more media streams by invoking `avformat_new_stream`
- Write header by invoking `avformat_write_header`
- Write media data by invoking `av_write_frame`
- Write trailer by invoking `av_write_trailer`
- Destroy muxing context by invoking `avformat_free_context`

Answer (score 1):

The example generates a raw bitstream - it is not a MP4. The example is only meant to demonstrate encoding, not muxing (the term for packaging one or more streams into a container file format like MP4).

Rename extension to .h264 and test with VLC. No idea if Chrome supports raw .h264 files.

To generate MP4 from this output, run

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy actually.mp4
```

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified more - I am looking for a way to achieve this via libavcodec i.e. a C program. Basically I want to know what the example code is missing. Encoding with the `ffmpeg` CLI is trivial, comparatively.

Comment: My ffmpeg command isn't encoding - it's muxing. See https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c which does both encoding and muxing afterwards.

Comment: Never said your command was encoding. I was saying that if I wanted to use the CLI to resolve this, I would have done the encoding in that fashion as well. In case it needs more clarification: the `encode_video.c` example is missing something that makes the video playable. I am looking for that "something" in libavcodec.

Comment: Video is playable - libavcodec can only encode and so it generates a raw bitstream, and so you need to give the output an extension of h264 if encoder is libx264. MP4 is a container which requires muxing carried out by libavformat. ffplay doesn't care much about the input extension. VLC surprisingly does.

Answer (score -1):

can only be played by ffplay, and VLC Player (as well as Google Chrome) fail to play the video.
Since ffplay is able to play the video, other media players can play it. You need to configure vlc to read X264 encoded video. Go to preference select all and change the demuxer to video H264